# Reveal hidden items when using up/down arrow on Ul reaches top/bottom of an overflow auto item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `ul` that I am scrolling up and down on. The `ul` has `overflow:auto` on it, so after a certain point the selected item is no longer visible. You can see an example of the problem at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/NjC58/34/

Currently I have the following code, borrowed largely from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903825/html-jquery-implement-arrow-down-on-ul-li):

```
var displayBoxIndex = -1;
var Navigate = function (diff) {
    displayBoxIndex += diff;
    var oBoxCollection = $("#leftDrop li");
    if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length) {
        displayBoxIndex = 0;
    }
    if (displayBoxIndex < 0) {
        displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
    }
    var cssClass = "selectedInitialNav";
    oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){ // 38-up, 40-down
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
        Navigate(1);

        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        Navigate(-1);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Thus, I am looking for a solution that will scroll the `overflow` to the top if you are pressing `down arrow` and get to the bottom of the visible `ul`, and if you are pressing `up arrow` and get to the top of the visible `ul` will scroll `overflow` down so that the selected `li` is at the bottom of the visible `ul`.

I have been looking for solutions using jQuery's [scroll function](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/), using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714096/jquery-auto-scroll-a-div-up-down), and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346011/jquery-scroll-to-an-element-within-an-overflowed-div) (which mentions `scrollTop`), but haven't actually found anything close to a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

One method you could try is by creating a function which handles the scrolling. It sets the scrollTop position of each item.

**ScrollUl function**

```
function scrollUl(){
    if(window.event.keyCode == 40){
        document.getElementById("parent").scrollTop = scrolLength;
        scrolLength = scrolLength + 19;  
    }           
    else if(window.event.keyCode == 38){            
        scrolLength = scrolLength - 19;  
        document.getElementById("parent").scrollTop = scrolLength;

    }
}
```

Then you should call the function within your `Navigate` function and you should ad an id to your `ul` like: `<ul id="parent">`

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94ndqmnr/1/)

This code still needs some improvements but it might help you getting your way.